# Closed form of the integral ${\large\int}_0^\infty e^{-x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{-24\!\;n\!\;x}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, infinite-product, q-series

While doing some numerical experiments, I discovered a curious integral that appears to have a simple closed form:
$${\large\int}_0^\infty e^{-x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{-24\!\;n\!\;x}\right)dx\stackrel{\color{gray}?}=\frac{\pi^2}{6\sqrt3}\tag1$$
Could you suggest any ideas how to prove it?

The infinite product in the integrand can be written using [q-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html):
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{-24\!\;n\!\;x}\right)=\left(e^{-24\!\;x};\,e^{-24\!\;x}\right)_\infty\tag2$$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To be somewhat explicit. One may perform the change of variable, $q=e^{-x}$, $dq=-e^{-x}dx$, giving
$$
{\large\int}_0^\infty e^{-x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{-24\!\;n\!\;x}\right)dx={\large\int}_0^1 \prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{24n}\right)dq\tag1
$$ then use the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product#Properties) (the [Euler pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem))
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{n}\right)=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^nq^{\large \frac{3n^2-n}2}
$$ to get

> $$
> {\large\int}_0^\infty e^{-x}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-e^{-24\!\;n\!\;x}\right)dx=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\large\int}_0^1(-1)^n q^{12 (3n^2-n)}dq=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(6n-1)^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6 \sqrt{3}}
> $$

The last equality is obtained by converting the series in terms of the [Hurwitz zeta](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#x) function and by using the [multiplication theorem](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11#v).

Comment: Where is the last equality shown?

Comment: You may convert the series to Hurwitz zeta function values, then reduce the result with the multiplication theorem:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function#Relation_to_Dirichlet_L-functions

Answer (score 6):

One may just apply the [Jacobi triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) to the [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function), then perform a termwise integration that leads to a multiple of $\zeta(2)$.

Comment: (+1) Can't we use something like Euler Pentagonal number theorem directly and evaluate the infinite series?

Comment: @r9m: oh, sure, that approach is explained very well in Olivier's answer.