# Conjectured value of a difficult integral with Dedekind eta functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus, conjectures

In my research on quantum groups I have the following conjecture:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\eta (2 i x)^8}{\eta (i x)^2 \eta (4 i x)^2}\,dx\,{\stackrel?=}\,\frac{K(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}{\pi}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\eta(ix)=e^{-\frac{\pi x}{12}}\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-e^{-2n\pi x})
\end{equation}
is the Dedekind eta function and
\begin{equation}
K(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{\Gamma^2(\tfrac14)}{4\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{equation}
is the [Elliptic integral singular value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValuek1.html).

This value has been guessed using Inverse symbolic calculator and then checked numerically to a high precision, but I do not have a proof.

**Question**: Is (1) true?

Comment: In the first post, you have been looking quite aggressive to several people who wanted to help you. Now, I delete my answer.

Comment: @Hans: as already said, it is enough to invoke the residue theorem, special values for the Dedekind eta function and the known relation between $K\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$. In my humble opinion, what is really missing here is some context, namely why the LHS of $(1)$ is somewhat relevant and some attempts made to prove such identity.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio unfortunately the context is very hard to explain, because it involves very technical stuff like conformal field theory, Lie algebras and so on, and also some guess work. Can you please eloborate on this remark *it is enough to invoke the residue theorem*? Can you at least write down the residue of which function and at what points?

Comment: @Hans: consider the third and the fourth row of the table after equation $(95)$ here - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html.

Comment: Let me ask you a simpler question: can you compute $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n+1} e^{-n^2 x}\right]^2\,dx $$ ? Your question is not really different from this one.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio so you convert the LHS of (1) to a quadruple sum, and then what? Where does the residue theorem come into play?

Comment: @Hans: no, I do not convert the integrand function as a quadruple sum, I convert it into a double product. And where the residue theorem comes into play is pretty clear from my last counter-question. I am going to open a thread about it, let us cover the basics before attacking more sophisticated problems.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you please stop being criptic and just give an outline of the answer detailing main steps, provided you have an answer? Or maybe you don't have an answer and just speculating?

Comment: @Hans: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602500/an-interesting-identity-involving-jacobi-theta-4-and-zeta2

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio in your case you convert the integral into a double sum. In the present case there will be a quadruple sum or a double sum (probably both of them divergent), as I mentioned earlier. I still don't see any residues nor in your question nor in this present case either. Also how do you plan to get an elliptic integral out of an dilogarithm is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @Hans: you have to compute the $L^2$ norm over $\mathbb{R}^+$ of $\theta_2(\sqrt{q})\theta_4(q^2)q^{-1/8}$, which is a product. In your case the elliptic integral comes from the square of $\eta(i)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio why wouldn't you just give an answer? I bet that's because you don't have it.

Comment: @Hans: No, that is not the correct reason. I mentioned that your question lacks some crucial context, and guided you through a solution nevertheless. Even reposting the exactly same question (with the same issues) is kind of debatable. And honestly speaking, if you do not care about providing crucial details, why should I? What is the purpose of having an answer without grasping the techniques behind it?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio your method in the linked question do not carry over to the present integral. The case you considered is too trivial. And what context do you need? I said it is related to very technical stuff from CFT.

Comment: Share your CFT knowledge with us :)

Comment: @Hans: First step: simplify the integrand function. For any $x>0$ we have
$$ \eta(ix) = q^{\frac{1}{24}}\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^{n}),\qquad q=e^{-2\pi x} $$

$$ \frac{\eta(2ix)^8}{\eta(ix)^2\eta(4ix)^2} = \frac{q^{\frac{2}{3}}\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^{2n})^8}{q^{\frac{5}{12}}\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n)^2(1-q^{4n})^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{\vartheta_4(q^2)\vartheta_2(\sqrt{q})}{q^{\frac{1}{8}}}\right]^2$$
where the last identity has been deduced through the third and fourth line of the table after eq.(95) [here][1]. Now

Comment: $$ \vartheta_2(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{(n+1/2)^2},\qquad \vartheta_4(q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n q^{n^2} $$
give
$$\frac{\vartheta_4(q^2)\vartheta_2(\sqrt{q})}{q^{\frac{1}{8}}} = \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n q^{\frac{m^2+m}{2}+2n^2}$$
$$\left[\frac{\vartheta_4(q^2)\vartheta_2(\sqrt{q})}{q^{\frac{1}{8}}}\right]^2 = \sum_{m,M,n,N\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^{n+N} q^{\frac{m^2+m+M^2+m}{2}+2(n^2+N^2)}$$
such that the wanted integral equals
$$\frac{1}{8\pi}\sum_{n,N,m,M\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{(-1)^{n+N}}{\frac{m+m^2+M+M^2}{2}+2(n^2+N^2)}. $$

Comment: The problem boils down to recalling the series representation of $\vartheta_3^2$ and the value of $\eta(i)^2$.

Comment: How to compute such series through the residue theorem is explained in the other thread. Now, respectfully, I disengage.

Comment: @skbmoore amazing solution! Do you also happen to know a proof for this one too?

Comment: I don't think there is any need to challenge anyone to produce an answer. @JackD'Aurizio is only trying to help here by providing an approach which he thinks is suitable for the current problem. If you see my answer below then your problem appears not that complicated, but the same technique is not helpful for the question Jack D'Aurizio is asking in the linked thread and thus I don't consider his integral as trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following solution uses the link between elliptic integrals and theta functions.

---

Let's use $q=e^{-\pi x} $ and then we define function $f$ via $$f(q) =q^{1/12}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})=\eta(ix)\tag{1}$$ Let $x=K(k') /K(k) $ where $k, k'$ are elliptic moduli complementary to each other and $K(k)=K $ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind. From the theory of elliptic integrals and theta functions we have
\begin{align}
f(q)=\eta(ix)&=2^{-1/3}\sqrt{\frac{2K} {\pi}} (kk') ^{1/6}\tag{2a}\\
f(q^2)=\eta(2ix)&=2^{-2/3}\sqrt {\frac {2K}{\pi}}k^{1/3}k'^{1/12}\tag{2b}\\
f(q^4)=\eta(4ix)&=2^{-13/12}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}\frac{k^{2/3}k'^{1/24}}{(1+k')^{1/4}}\tag{2c}
\end{align}
The integrand in question is $$\frac{f^8(q^2)} {f^2(q)f^2(q^4)}=2^{-5/2}\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2kk'^{1/4}(1+k')^{1/2} $$ and we have $$\frac{dx} {dk} =\frac{dx}{dq}\cdot\frac {dq} {dk} =-\frac{1} {\pi q} \cdot\frac{\pi^2 q}{2kk'^2K^2} =-\frac{\pi} {2kk'^2K^2}\tag{3}$$ so that the desired integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}k'^{-7/4}(1+k')^{1/2}\,dk=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}\,dt\tag{4}$$ (via substitution $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}=t$) which is evaluated easily via Beta/Gamma functions to obtain desired result.

---

We were lucky that after switching from $x$ to $k$ the elliptic integral $K$ got cancelled and the resulting integral was having an algebraic function as an integrand. Thus the original integral appears to be designed to have such a nice evaluation. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1812328/72031) for another instance of this technique.

Comment: You rock, man! Great job!