# An integration of product $(1-x^n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, products

Prove $$\int_0^1\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)dx=\frac{4\pi\sqrt3}{\sqrt{23}}\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}3}{\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}2}.$$
In fact, product $(1-x^n)$ is difficult to compute, I hope you can show me some ideas, thank you!

Comment: You should first transform the expression of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)$ into a (famous !) series given [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem).

Comment: @JeanMarie Ohh I didn't know about this thing. Thank you for that :)

Comment: $\int_0^1\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^{24n})dx$ had already been considered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541601/closed-form-of-the-integral-large-int-0-infty-e-x-prod-n-1-infty-left/1541666#1541666

Comment: This is an ongoing contest problem ! See problem U382 here : https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2016-04/mr_4_2016_problems_4.pdf

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Yeah, thanks!

Comment: Some philosophical question here. Did someone tried to figure out why the number $23$ is there? **Why** $23$ and not $29$?

Comment: This is (4) in Glasser, [Some Integrals of the Dedekind $\eta$-Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1992.pdf), specialized to $y = 23/24$.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We may use the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) and get $$\int_{0}^{1}\prod_{n\geq1}\left(1-x^{n}\right)dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-1\right)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k\left(3k-1\right)/2}dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{2}{3k^{2}-k+2}
 $$ and now we can use the well known summation formula $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(-1\right)^{n}f\left(n\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\csc\left(\pi z\right)f(z)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\} 
 $$ and since we have poles at $z=\frac{1}{6}\left(1\pm i\sqrt{23}\right)
 $ we can conclude.

Comment: Efficient! (+1)

Comment: Good job! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I didn't manage to find Marco's answer I seemed to recall, so I will just re-do the proof.

By [Euler pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) we have
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}(1-x^k) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^m x^{\frac{3m^2-m}{2}} \tag{1}$$
hence by termwise integration the initial integral equals
$$ \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2(-1)^m}{3m^2-m+2} \tag{2}$$
and the last series can be computed through the following identity, that comes from the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function:

$$ \tanh(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8x}{4x^2+(2n+1)^2\pi^2} \tag{3}$$
or through
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b} \tag{4}$$
and [the dilogarithm reflection and duplication formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html). Putting all together,
$$ \boxed{\int_{0}^{1}\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-x^k)\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}\sinh{\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}{3}}}{{\sqrt{23}\cosh{\frac{\pi\sqrt{23}}{2}}}} }}$$
follows.

Comment: you must really be fond of special functions

Comment: +1 for the use of Euler pentagonal theorem. I was trying to use the link between eta function and elliptic integrals but did not succeed as it led to very cryptic results.