# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, infinite-product

The following integral appeared this summer on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1652928). However it received no answer until today.
$$I=\lim_{n\to \infty } \int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)(1+x^2)\dots(1+x^n)}=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)}$$
I have learnt recently from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) that: $$\frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n)}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)\Rightarrow I=\int_0^1\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)dx$$
I suspect this has a closed form since a similar [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883140/515527) to the last equality appeared here on MSE before; however this one is a bit different since the product goes only on odd powers and I don't see how to make a connection between the two of them, so I will appreciate some help with that.

Comment: The series expansion of the integrand is [here](http://oeis.org/A081362). An alternate form of the problem is $$I = \int_0^1 (q;q^2)_\infty \,dq,$$ where $(a;q)_\infty$ is the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html).

Comment: With a lot of help from Mathematica I can only obtain a (conjectural) infinite series form for the integral
$$I=8 \pi\sqrt{3}   \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{p(n) \sinh \left(\frac{1}{6} \pi  \sqrt{48 n+23}\right)}{\sqrt{48 n+23} \left(2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \pi  \sqrt{48 n+23}\right)-1\right)}$$
where $p(n)$ is the number of unrestricted partitions of the integer n.

This leads me to suspect that $I$ does not have a closed form.

Comment: By numeric computation, this integral is about $0.42888151226615025372$. If you put it in WolframAlpha or RIES, you will see that this does not look like anything with a closed form.

Comment: $I=\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac2{(-1;x)_\infty}\,\mathrm dx\approx 0.428882.$

Answer (score 1):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Analysis of the production.}}$

Let us consider the production
$$p(x)=\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{1+x^n},\quad x\in(0,1).$$

First,
$$\prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-x^{2k+1})\cdot\prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\log(1-x^{2k}) = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\log(1-x^k),$$
so
$$p(x)=\prod\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{1+x^n} = \prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-x^{2k+1}),\quad x\in(0,1).\tag1$$

At the second, looks right the prove
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\ln(1-x^{2k+1})
= -\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{(2k+1)m}}{m}
= -\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m(1-x^{2m})}\\
= -\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2m}\left(\dfrac1{1-x^m} + \dfrac1{1+x^m}\right)
= -\dfrac12\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{x^{km}}{m}+\dfrac{(-x)^{km}}{m}\right),$$
$$\ln p(x)= \dfrac12\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\ln(1-x^k)+\ln(1+x^k)\right),$$
$$\ln p(x)= \dfrac13\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\ln(1-x^k),$$
$$p(x)=\sqrt[3]{\prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-x^k)} = \sqrt[3]{(x;x)_\infty}, \tag{*}$$
where $(x,x)_\infty$ is [q-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html).

However, identity $(*)$ $\color{red}{\textrm{is wrong}}$ (see [Wolfram Alpha counterexample](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bprod_(k%3D1,infty)%201%2F(1%2B0.5%5Ek),%20cbrt(QPochhammer%5B0.5%5D)%7D)).

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Results.}}$

Right identity is
$$p(x)=\dfrac2{(-1;x)_\infty}\tag2$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bprod(n%3D1,infty)(1%2B0.3%5En),1%2F2%20QPochhammer%5B-1,.3%5D%7D)).

There are not detalized information about $q$-Pochhammer symbols, so [the value of integral is calculated numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_(0,1)%20(2.0%2FQPochhammer%5B-1,%20x%5D)%20dx), wherein

$$\boxed{I=\int\limits_0^1 p(x)\,\mathrm dx \approx 0.428882.}$$

Comment: @Zacky A possible error in the proof is a permutation of the members of a two-dimensional alternating signs sequence.