# Integral $\int\limits_{0}^{1} \prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(1-q^{2k})(1+q^{2k+1})(1+q^{2k+3})dq$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int\limits_0^1 \prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-q^{2k}\right)\left(1+q^{2k+1}\right)\left(1+q^{2k+3}\right)dq
= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}}
  \left(\frac{e^{\pi a^{5/2}/ b}-c}
             {e^{\pi a^{5/2}/ b}+e^{\pi a^{3/2}/ b}+c}\right)
$$

I want to find the value of $a,b,c$

Sorry I have nothing much to show in effort. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: are all exponential terms on the RHS the same by intent or is it a typo?

Comment: @gt6989b You are right. I have edited the post.

Comment: Possible useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040367/515527 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883140/515527

Comment: Even more useful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html

Comment: @Zacky Thanks..

Comment: I think I saw it somewhere on brilliant.org I guess

Comment: Indeed @Digamma, this is an open problem, with a quick search on brilliant I found it. See here: https://brilliant.org/problems/a-q-triple-product-integral-2/?ref_id=1561212

Comment: A fundamental problem: the product on the LHS is equal to $0$ hence for $k=0$ the we got that $(1-q^0)(1+q^1)(1+q^3)=(1-1)(1+q)(1+q^3)=0$.