# Show that $\int_0^1 \prod_{n\geq 1} (1-x^n) \, dx = \frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}\sinh(\frac{\pi}{3}\sqrt{23})}{\sqrt{23}\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{23})}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, infinite-product

$$\int_0^1 \prod_{n\geq 1} (1-x^n) \, dx = \frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}\sinh(\frac{\pi}{3}\sqrt{23})}{\sqrt{23}\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{23})}$$

This monstrous expression is from Tolaso Network (tolaso.com.gr). I have no idea how to approach it - converting the product to a sum of logarithms does no good, and one cannot switch the order of product/integral either. The product in itself doesn't converge to anything nice either.

I am interested in seeing the proof of the above identity, as well as an explanation of how exactly $\sqrt{23}$ becomes involved in such a deceptive integral. Both real and complex analytic solutions are welcome. A proof without the pentagonal number theorem would be nice as well, since that somewhat trivializes the problem.

Comment: Use the pentagonal number theorem, then switch order of sum and integration, the resulting series is easy to evaluate using contour integration.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541601/closed-form-of-the-integral-large-int-0-infty-e-x-prod-n-1-infty-left/1541666#1541666

Comment: This is (4) is Glasser, [Some Integrals of the Dedekind $\eta$-Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1992.pdf), specialized to $y = 23/24$.

Answer (score 10):

Note that
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^mx^{m(3m+1)/2}
$$
(Euler's pentagonal number formula), so the integral equals
\begin{align}
I&=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^m\frac2{3m^2+m+2}\\
&=\frac4{\sqrt{23}}
\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty(-1)^m\left(\frac{1}{m+(1-\sqrt{23})/6}
-\frac{1}{m+(1+\sqrt{23})/6}\right).
\end{align}
Now you can attack this with identities for the digamma function.

Comment: Those digamma identities are...?

Comment: The Wolfram MathWorld page has all the ones  you'll need:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by Pisco, use the [Pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem), for $|x|<1$,
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-x^n)=\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^m x^{\frac{3m^2-m}{2}}.$$
Then by integrating each term (here some details are needed), we get
$$2\sum\limits_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m }{3m^2-m+2}.$$
Now note that the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial at the denominator is the number $-23$.

Can you take it from here?