# Integrating Euler's function

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $\phi(x)$ be the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function).

As presented in the [Special values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function#Special_values) section there,

> Using the [Pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem), exchanging sum and integral, and then invoking complex-analytic methods, one derives
> $$\int_0^1 \phi(x) \, dx =  \frac{8\sqrt{3/23}\pi\sinh(\sqrt{23}\pi/6)}{2\cosh(\sqrt{23}\pi/3)-1} \approx 1-0.631587464068566$$.

Can anybody assert if this result is actually correct, and provide a reference for it? As stated in the section,

> This result needs concrete references, as I have been unable to verify it

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019758/show-that-int-01-prod-n-geq-1-1-xn-dx-frac4-pi-sqrt3-sinh-fra?noredirect=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883140/an-integration-of-product-1-xn. The complex analytic method being referenced in the Wikipedia article is the well-known formula
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}f\left(k\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\csc\left(\pi z\right)f(z)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\},$$
which follows from the residue theorem.

Comment: The result given in both questions I linked can be shown to be equivalent to yours by some trigonometric identities.

Comment: A correct/better version of this is (4) in Glasser, [Some Integrals of the Dedekind $\eta$-Function](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1992.pdf), specialized to $y = 23/24$ plus a few identities.

Comment: @projectilemotion That is a gorgeous formula! How have I not seen in before.

Comment: @K.defaoite It's beautiful indeed! There are several assumptions that $f$ needs to satisfy which I forgot to mention above, see [this article](http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/complex/summation-series-residue.pdf). There is a similar formula
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(k\right)=-\sum\left\{ \textrm{residues of }\pi\cot\left(\pi z\right)f(z)\textrm{ at }f\left(z\right)\textrm{'s poles}\right\}.$$
From my experience, this formula is rarely taught in complex analysis courses.